# Running a PHP or MySQL script to do a task after time intervals

Tags: php, mysql

How Can I write a PHP script or MySQL script to do a repetitive task after a period of time? One example of this could be to delete the top row of a specific table in the database every 120 seconds.

Comment: http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.1/en/create-event.html

Comment: use cron job (scheduled task in windows) to run a script to run the query

Comment: PHP is not timed, hence you cannot use a PHP timer. But you could do DELETE FROM table_name WHERE id=1 if you have IDs or else DELETE FROM table_name LIMIT 1 - then initiate the script every 120 seconds by another method.

Answer (score 8):

Use [EVENTS](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.1/en/create-event.html)

```
CREATE EVENT delete_top_event
    ON SCHEDULE
      EVERY 2 MINUTE
    DO
      DELETE FROM your_table order by some_column desc limit 1;
```

Comment: And do not forget enable mysql event scheduler with `SET GLOBAL event_scheduler = ON;`.

Comment: Does this run automatically on Create or you have to call it?

Comment: @Mihai: Yes: *Not specifying STARTS is the same as using STARTS CURRENT_TIMESTAMP—that is, the action specified for the event begins repeating immediately upon creation of the event.*